# Excel concatenate

Tags: excel, concatenation

I would like to concatenate data from two cells into one cell. I would also like to only combine those cells that have the same ID.

Task ID Name

4355.2  Participant

4355.2  Leader

4462.1  Online

4462.1  Quick

4597.1  Slide

4597.1  One Page

4597.1  One Topic

For example, for this, I would like a cell for 4355.2 with "Participant, Leader" as the data in that cell. The same type of data for 4462.1 with "Online and Quick" as the data for that cell.

Task ID    Name

4355.2     Participant, Leader

Is there a way to do that in Excel?

4462.1     Online, Quick

Comment: Is it a one-time operation or will you have to do this often ? Is it possible to have more than 2 "Name" for the same "Task ID" ?

Comment: It's a one-time operation for this report. And yes, it is possible for there to be more than one name for the same task ID. As seen by the task ID of 4355.2 and the two names: Participant and leader.

Comment: It appears 4597.1 Has 3 names so I guess arbitrary many names.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data is in `A1:B8`, and sorted.

in C2, `=IF(OR(A2>A1,A1="Task ID"),B2,C1&", "&B2)`, and copy this down to the end of the data
Copy column A to column D, and remove duplicates *(tell excel not to expand the selection)*
In E2, `=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(D2,A:A),1)` and copy this down to the end of the de-duplicated data in column D