# Excel concatenate the column based on other column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
 I have data in excel like this 

   A         B      C

   p1       ABC    2
   p2wt     ABC    3
   p3       EFG    1
   p3wtke   EFG    1
   p9r      EFG    2
```

I'm trying to sum up C column if B column has same data and concatenate A column data. And data looks  like

```
    A             B       C

   p1-p2wt       ABC     5      
   p3-p3wtke-p9r EFG     4
```

I tried using `=SUMIFS(C1:C5,A1:A9,B1)`  but it is giving #value, and how do i concate A? I tried [Excel concatenate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195148/excel-concatenate), but is A2>A1 in this link is for number fields?

Comment: What Excel are you using?

Comment: you can concatenate using `A1 & A2`

Comment: Ms Excel 2010 version

Comment: Is column B always sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a helper column.

In D1 put:

```
=IF(B1<>B2,A1,A1&"-"&D2)
```

Then copy/drag down the data set.

[image]

The in another column create a list of the unique values in column B.  I put mine in G.

Then in F1 I put:

```
=VLOOKUP(G1,B:D,3,FALSE)
```

And in H1 I put:

```
=SUMIF(B:B,G1,C:C)
```

Then copies/dragged down.

[image]

Comment: For me in F column there will be blanks, how do get it with out blanks in your side

Comment: How do i get F column without blanks (with no filters)