# Excel concatenation multiple values into a single cell based on condition

Tags: excel

## Hi guys I'm new to excel and i would like to concatenate the country names into a single cell separated by '/'for the particular corresponding customer as shown in the below

colA1 colB1

A   India

A   UK

A   USA

A   Japan
**A India/UK/USA/Japan**

B   India

B   UK

B   USA

B   Japan

## **B India/UK/USA/Japan**

i am expecting the results in the above highlighted row using excel.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I gave you a simple answer and asked twice for you to put relevant information in the original question instead of adding information in comments. I have now deleted my answer, which should mean you have the opportunity to read this (stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then improve your question) and then improve your question by adding that information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel concatenate the column based on other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40430437/excel-concatenate-the-column-based-on-other-column)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to concatenate cells is by using `&`. Just use it between cell names and it should work.
In order to add other characters in between the text on the concatenated cells (including spaces), use `""`. 
So, in order to fulfill your request, you should use something like the below (assuming the cells you want to concatenate are in column A:

```
=A1&"/"&A2&"/"&A3&"/"&A4
```

Considering you would like to add "A" to the first word (India) but not to the others, you can try the below formula:

```
=(A1&"/"&RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-2)&"/"&RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-2))&"/"&RIGHT(A4,LEN(A4)-2)
```

It will consider A1 in full, A2 in full minus the first 2 characters and so forth. You can use the same formula for part B if you replace the cells within it. Hope that's what you're looking for.